# Is an empty dependency array for React.useEffect not permissible?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, use-effect

I have a child React component that is passed an `itemList` prop from its parent component.  This `itemList` is an object array containing data from an endpoint.

The first thing I want to do within the child component is translate `itemList` to be more complex, meaning for each object in the array to have more/different properties, etc.  I accomplish this via an `itemList.map` function call.

Because this is a one time operation, my thought was to just have an empty dependency array, like this:

```
type ObjectMap = {
  key: string,
  text: string,
  parentId?: string|null
};

const [objectItemList, setObjectItemList] = React.useState<Array<ObjectMap>>([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (isEmpty(objectItemList)) {
    const localObjectItemList: Array<ObjectMap> = itemList.map((item, idx) => {
      type ObjectKey = keyof typeof item; // Union of the object array element's keys
      const keyValue = String(item[objectMap.key as ObjectKey]);
      const textValue = String(item[objectMap.text as ObjectKey]);
      let parentIdValue: string|null = String(item[objectMap.parentId as ObjectKey]);
      parentIdValue = parentIdValue === 'null' ? null : parentIdValue;
      return {key: keyValue, text: textValue, parentId: parentIdValue};
    });

    setObjectItemList(localObjectItemList);
  }
}
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps    
}, []); // Including objectItemList cause "Too many renders" error
```

You can see that I'm suppressing the error but what's confusing is that I would have thought that just the empty dependency array alone would inform `eslint` to not complain about "missing dependencies".

By the way, as my comment in the code illustrates, if I do include `objectItemList` as a dependency then I get the other error mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ESLint is not smart enough to understand the context everytime, it's a set of objective measurements. If you want to run something once, guaranteed, use an empty dependency array and suppress the warning. It's a warning, not an error.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need useState and useEffect at this case. Because the component will rerender if props are changed

```
const objectItemList = itemList.map(...)
```

Comment: One thing though, if you do it your way, and let's assume that the calculations within `itemList.map(...)` are complex, then it's going to have to recalculate everything upon every re-render, correct?

Comment: @RobertW in that case you can use `useMemo` React hook to avoid recalculation on each re-render